# How to select the latest daily data from a table?

Tags: sql-server, windows, t-sql

I have a table for Logging. In this table there is a column type datetime. how can i select the latest daily records? Could someon please help me?

Thanks!

**Update!**
In this table there are the following columns:
InventoryNr, SerialNr, Oldusername, OlduserId, oldcostcenter, newusername, newuserid, newcostcenter, changedby, changedate.

Here the devices will be inserted automatically. So if a monitor is detected on a computer, it will be recorded in this table. However if i move the monitor to another pc it will be recorded once more. But in some cases a monitor can "jump" between two PCs.  And with PC's it is the same. If a PC's owner has been changed, then it will be inserted here automatically etc. So if i run this query, i need only the latest rows from a device, from that current day. Hope you can understand now what i meant.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you better define "the latest daily"? How many rows do you want? Do you want the last n rows, all the rows from today, only rows if they occurred today? More details are better than less details.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: by the latest daily i mean the following. If i run the query i only want to see the rows what on the current day lastely have been inserted

Answer (score 1):

To get the last 20 rows no matter when they happened:

```
SELECT TOP (20) cols FROM dbo.LoggingTable ORDER BY EventDate DESC;
```

To get all the rows that happened today, in descending order:

```
SELECT cols FROM dbo.LoggingTable
  WHERE EventDate >= DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
  ORDER BY EventDate DESC;
```

To get only the last 20 rows, as long as they happened today (meaning you could get < 20 rows):

```
SELECT TOP (20) cols FROM dbo.LoggingTable
  WHERE EventDate >= DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
  ORDER BY EventDate DESC;
```

I strongly recommend against applying any formulas to the column.

Comment: +1 Will `DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))` will be reevaluated for each row ?

Comment: What about cast to `Date ` - (cast the getDate func) ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir  Cast to Date may work for SQL Server 2008. We don't know what version the OP is using. This will work on all versions regardless of the data type or version, and is no slower than cast to date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select yourFields from yourTable
group by yourFieldDate,yourOtherFields
having yourFieldDate= MAX(yourFieldDate)
```

Comment: I dont see any connection to _having_ or _max_

Comment: This assumes the user only wants the *last* row inserted. And is much more cumbersome than using `TOP ... ORDER BY yourDateField DESC`.

Comment: this will output all the records inserted at the latest date.

Answer (score 0):

If using SQL 2008, you could:

`SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE TimeStamp > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC`